# Entity Framework 4 DeleteObject not showing

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following linq:

```
     var wcd = dbContext.Programs.Where(p => p.Id == Id).ToList();
     dbContext.DeleteObject(wcd); 
     SaveChanges();
```

I get a message saying that I do not have a definition for DeleteObject in my Model.
I can though do SaveChanges(),etc.

I tried the following:

```
        var wcd = dbContext.Programs.Where(p => p.Id == Id).ToList();
        dbContext.Programs.Remove(wcd);
```

but I get the following
  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet
 .Remove  has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a DbContext?  If so you're going to need to use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which is part of your DbSet:

EDIT:

You need to loop through your list and remove then individually:

```
foreach (var wc in wcd.ToList())
{
    dbContext.Programs.Remove(wc);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: var wcd = dbContext.Programs.Where(p => p.Id == Id).ToList();
dbContext.pasl_WaterChemistryDetail.Remove(wcd); is what I tried but get the error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet .Remove  has some invalid arguments